# In manifest.mf Trusted-Library: true giving me mixed code prompts

Tags: applet, java-7, manifest.mf, jar-signing

My system contains four jars. One jar contains [Mixedcode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html)(applet called from javascript). The jar containing the mixed code accesses other jars also. I added the attribute **Trusted-Library : true** and **Permissions: all-permissions** in manifest.mf(I'm using **[Java7 update25](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u25-relnotes-1955741.html)**) of the jar containing the mixed code. All the jars are self-signed. Now the problem is I'm still getting the mixed code warning, which Oracle introduced in **[Java 7 update21](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u21-relnotes-1932873.html)**.

Should i add the attributes in manifest.mf file of other jars also ?

My observations are:

After adding **Trusted-Library : true** and **Permissions: all-permissions** in all jars(doesn't matter whether they are signed or unsigned) it works fine. All the jars are loaded.

But why do i need to add these particular attributes in all the jars(Some of jars are third party jars)?
According to definition of Mixedcode and usage of the attribute **Trusted-Library: true** it should allow other jars once it is updated in Manifest.mf file of jar containing the applet.